# Plotting a 3D surface plot of a surface of revolution

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've got an equation of a surface of revolution and I want to plot it. Say for a general equation z = ax^2 + by^2 + c.

For example, for 1 = x^2 + y^2 and 0 <= z <= 1, which is a cylinder of height 1 and radius 1, how do I go about plotting this?

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: That's what I am having trouble with, I am very new to latex and I've tried googling how to do it but all I get are how to plot sets of coordinates, not equations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pgfplots` manual can be found [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). Always remember show what research you've done towards a problem before posting a question - as @Andrew said, people will be more likely to help you

`pgfplots` can be used to plot in three dimensions, using the command `\addplot3`

Parametric equations are the way forwards here, for a cylinder this is:

```
x(u,v) = cos(u)
y(u,v) = sin(u)
z(u,v) = v
```

The syntax for this in `pgfplots` is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[axis equal]

\addplot3 [surf,
           colormap/hot2, %colour scheme
           domain=0:360, %sets range for x
           y domain=0:1, %sets range for y
           samples=20, %number of samples taken
           z buffer=sort]
    (
        {cos(x)},
        {sin(x)},
        {y}
    );

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives the result:

[image: A cylinder]