# Drawing a cylinder inside a 3D frame

Tags: tikz-pgf

There are many questions related to cylinders but mine is a little different. I would like to draw a cylinder inside a 3D frame as shown. I want to keep the 3D planes the way they are shown. However, I am unable to move the green cylinder to other positions and to change the cylinder size. I can also draw a parametric cylinder but its surface is meshed or "grid-ified" which I don't want. Is there a way to change the size/location of the green cylinder or remove the grids on the parametric cylinder and change its size?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal]
\addplot3 [surf,
   colormap/hot2, %colour scheme
   domain=0:360, %sets range for x
   y domain=0:1, %sets range for y
   samples=20, %number of samples taken
   z buffer=sort]
(
{cos(x)},
{sin(x)},
{y}
);

\node[cylinder, draw, shape aspect=.5, 
  cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder end fill=green!50, 
  minimum height=1cm,
  cylinder body fill=green!25, opacity=0.5, 
  scale=3, rotate=90]  {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: cylinder]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: I guess I missed out the \usepackage{pgfplots}. I will add it.

Comment: You also forgot `\documentclass{}` etc.

Comment: Oh, sorry, one min. Now I understand you.

Comment: @AndréC Done. Please take a look

Comment: I'm guessing you found this code somewhere on the web. Can you tell where it came from?

Comment: I think from here tex.stackexchange and maybe from other samples I have

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337707/plotting-a-3d-surface-plot-of-a-surface-of-revolution/352978 is the source for the parametric cylinder